Código Script si funciona en vsc pero al cargar en sitio web ya no se ve el contenido
El código lo copie y pegue de otro sitio, es para que se vean fantasmas en mi sitio web con javascript. Pero no carga las imagenes que deberian de ser 30 al quererlo ver en línea.
NOTA: En vsc funciona correcto.


var Ghost = function() {
  var a = {};
  if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
    if (jQuery.browser.version < 8) {
      return a
    }
  }
  a.html = '<div class="ghost"></div>';
  a.element = null;
  a.timer = null;
  a.interval = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1e3) + 1e3;
  a.directionX = Math.round(Math.random());
  a.directionY = Math.round(Math.random());
  if (a.directionX == 0) {
    a.directionX = -1
  }
  if (a.directionY == 0) {
    a.directionY = -1
  }
  a.screenWidth = null;
  a.screenHeight = null;
  a.elementWidth = 150;
  a.elementHeight = 145;
  a.init = function() {
    a.getBrowserSize();
    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
      a.getBrowserSize()
    });
    a.element = jQuery(a.html);
    a.timer = window.setInterval(a.move, a.interval);
    jQuery("body").append(a.element);
    a.move(true);
    a.move();
    return a
  };
  a.move = function(b) {
    var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 100);
    var d = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 100);
    var e = a.element.offset().left;
    var f = a.element.offset().top;
    var g = e + a.directionX * c;
    var h = f + a.directionY * d;
    var i = a.screenWidth - a.elementWidth - 20;
    var j = a.screenHeight - a.elementHeight;
    if (g > i) {
      g = i;
      a.directionX = -a.directionX
    } else if (g < 0) {
      g = 0;
      a.directionX = -a.directionX
    }
    if (h > j) {
      h = j;
      a.directionY = -a.directionY
    } else if (h < 0) {
      h = 0;
      a.directionY = -a.directionY
    }
    var k = Math.random() - .1;
    if (k < .4) {
      k = .4
    }
    if (b) {
      a.element.css("top", Math.floor(Math.random() * a.screenHeight - a.elementHeight));
      a.element.css("left", Math.floor(Math.random() * a.screenWidth - a.elementWidth))
    } else {
      a.element.removeClass("moving-left");
      a.element.removeClass("moving-right");
      if (g > e) {
        a.element.addClass("moving-right")
      } else if (g < e) {
        a.element.addClass("moving-left")
      }
      a.element.stop();
      a.element.animate({
        top: h,
        left: g,
        opacity: k
      }, {
        duration: a.interval,
        easing: "swing"
      })
    }
  };
  a.getBrowserSize = function() {
    a.screenWidth = jQuery(document).width();
    a.screenHeight = jQuery(document).height()
  };
  a.init();
  return a
}
jQuery(function() {
  var Ghosts = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    Ghosts.push(new Ghost());
  }
})
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript' /></script>



Me ayudan porfas

¿Has puesto todo en una sola línea? Es bastante difícil de revisar. Por favor, lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] y edita la pregunta.

Ya le quite el estilo... Para le lectura, no le puedo quitar más ya que después el código no se reproduce tampoco en vsc. Es lo Max que le puedo quitar para que se pueda reproducir en los navegadores...

Considera en utilizar https://beautifier.io/ para mejorar la legibilidad del código. Saludos.

Tl vez el código no funciona porque no tienes ningpun código css, recuerda siempre poner un [mcve]

deberia de funcionarte de la siguiente forma:


var Ghost = function() {
  var a = {};
  if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
    if (jQuery.browser.version < 8) {
      return a;
    }
  }
  a.html = '<div class="ghost"></div>';
  a.element = null;
  a.timer = null;
  a.interval = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1e3) + 1e3;
  a.directionX = Math.round(Math.random());
  a.directionY = Math.round(Math.random());
  if (a.directionX == 0) {
    a.directionX = -1;
  }
  if (a.directionY == 0) {
    a.directionY = -1;
  }
  a.screenWidth = null;
  a.screenHeight = null;
  a.elementWidth = 150;
  a.elementHeight = 145;
  a.init = function() {
    a.getBrowserSize();
    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
      a.getBrowserSize();
    });
    a.element = jQuery(a.html);
    a.timer = window.setInterval(a.move, a.interval);
    jQuery("body").append(a.element);
    a.move(true);
    a.move();
    return a;
  };
  a.move = function(b) {
    var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 100);
    var d = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 100);
    var e = a.element.offset().left;
    var f = a.element.offset().top;
    var g = e + a.directionX * c;
    var h = f + a.directionY * d;
    var i = a.screenWidth - a.elementWidth - 20;
    var j = a.screenHeight - a.elementHeight;
    if (g > i) {
      g = i;
      a.directionX = -a.directionX;
    } else if (g < 0) {
      g = 0;
      a.directionX = -a.directionX;
    }
    if (h > j) {
      h = j;
      a.directionY = -a.directionY;
    } else if (h < 0) {
      h = 0;
      a.directionY = -a.directionY;
    }
    var k = Math.random() - 0.1;
    if (k < 0.4) {
      k = 0.4;
    }
    if (b) {
      a.element.css(
        "top",
        Math.floor(Math.random() * a.screenHeight - a.elementHeight)
      );
      a.element.css(
        "left",
        Math.floor(Math.random() * a.screenWidth - a.elementWidth)
      );
    } else {
      a.element.removeClass("moving-left");
      a.element.removeClass("moving-right");
      if (g > e) {
        a.element.addClass("moving-right");
      } else if (g < e) {
        a.element.addClass("moving-left");
      }
      a.element.stop();
      a.element.animate({
        top: h,
        left: g,
        opacity: k
      }, {
        duration: a.interval,
        easing: "swing"
      });
    }
  };
  a.getBrowserSize = function() {
    a.screenWidth = jQuery(document).width();
    a.screenHeight = jQuery(document).height();
  };
  a.init();
  return a;
};

jQuery(function() {
  var Ghosts = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    Ghosts.push(new Ghost());
  }
});
.ghost {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 145px;
  z-index: 10001;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background: transparent url('https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/b/R29vZ2xl/AVvXsEjchwswS3RXbzmjUSCbx25XhX9g1IhrY_Z5gm8dVtmDD8nONbXXSssz0r-VIy0j8wkHzPme4SNwbBMutF2KHhWmuCyqAHK6pd3SRoFtCQQzFg3Wc4T1XaY7krvV0AgMN0LWOzNj4syZoxY/s1600/fantasma.png') no-repeat;
}

.ghost.moving-left {
  -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  filter: fliph;
  /*IE*/
}
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>




¿Cómo responde este código a la pregunta? Pulsa en [edit] y describe el código. Lee [answer].
